# Preventing duplicate entries during signing up

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a checking process during signing up so that an existing username and e-mail can’t be used with a new registration. After validation, the data is stored immediately and we can’t see what causes the problem. Maybe we should use some type of locking?

We use a unique hash in the form, which we swap after every process, somehow it still occurs that a user registration is stored twice because of double clicking or other event.

Do you have any ideas how we could prevent double entries?

Thank you.

Comment: unique constraint on your non duplicatable fields?

Comment: Thanks, we have thought about it, but we are not sure yet if this is the only possible way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want values to be unique in a table, then use a `unique` constraint in the table:

```
alter table t
    add constraint unq_username_email unique (username, email);
```

Let the database do the work, so it guarantees data integrity.  Then you don't have to worry about race conditions.

I should note:  You might want *two* unique constraints.  It is unclear exactly what you want to be unique:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_username unique (username);
alter table t add constraint unq_email unique (email);
```

Comment: Thanks, we have thought about it, but we are not sure yet if this is the only possible way to solve it.

Comment: @kz88 . . . I don't know what you are thinking but unique constraints/indexes are the right way to implement this functionality.